# trying to add user to database js

Tags: javascript, json, database, api

this code is used to add user to database

```
export const addUserInDB = (userEntityModel: UserEntityModel) => {
userEntityModel.id = '7';
 return fetch(usersUrl, {
 method: 'POST',
 body: JSON.stringify(userEntityModel),
 }).then((res) => res.json());
};
```

but it only returns this code in the database

```
{
  "id": "Tcvpety"
}
```

And i want something like this

```
{
  "id": "5",
  "login": "luigi",
  "password": "luigi125",
  "email": "lluis.rubies@test.com",
  "country": "Japan",
  "type": "Customer",
  "language": [
    "Japanese",
    "English"
  ]
},
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Have you tried querying the API for that ID afterwards?  I would expect that a GET on that endpoint (`usersUrl`) with `id=Tcvpety` as an argument would return the user data that you POSTed. (Read the API documentation to confirm.)

Comment: @Malte yes i tried the query the api with the id and it only returns the id (its a fake api)

Comment: If the API is fake, does it store anything that you POST? A POST action is not supposed to give you back more than a confirmation if your action succeeded, and possibly a tag or handle to the new record. So the result of the function `addUserInDB`is as expected. For a subsequent GET query (with that id) to return the user data, the service behind the API must be able to persist the POSTed data. I would not expect that from a fake.